# Accessing azure blob exited with code zero

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to traverse the blobs in a Azure blob container called "users". I am using a Console application. When the code hits `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync()` point the process terminates with the message

> exited with code 0

My code is as below:

```
                string storageConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("users");

            BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
            //BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(
            //                                                                        prefix: null,
            //                                                                        useFlatBlobListing: true,
            //                                                                        blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None,
            //                                                                        maxResults: null,
            //                                                                        currentToken: blobContinuationToken,
            //                                                                        options: null,
            //                                                                        operationContext: null);
            var resultSegment = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, blobContinuationToken);
```

I tried both the last line and the commented line. But the same outout. exits with code 0. Appreciate some help on this.

**FULL CODE**

1. AzureStorageAnalyser.cs class

   ```
    public class AzureStorageAnalyser
    {
        public async void GetBlobFileProperties()
        {
            try
            {
                string storageConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=***;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
                CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("users");

            BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
            //BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(
            //                                                                        prefix: null,
            //                                                                        useFlatBlobListing: true,
            //                                                                        blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None,
            //                                                                        maxResults: null,
            //                                                                        currentToken: blobContinuationToken,
            //                                                                        options: null,
            //                                                                        operationContext: null);
            var resultSegment = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, blobContinuationToken);
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobItems = resultSegment.Results;

            List<string> fileUris = new List<string>();
            foreach (var blobItem in blobItems)
            {
                fileUris.Add(blobItem.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Main method

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        AzureStorageAnalyser analyser = new AzureStorageAnalyser();
        analyser.GetBlobFileProperties();
    }
   ```

Comment: Is your code in the `Main` method in your console application?

Comment: Is this function marked as async and are you awaiting the calls all the way up the chain ? Please show your complete code

Comment: @GauravMantri no i create a seperate class and in it theres a public method. I instantiate   the class from main method of the console application

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the complete code. More than likely you're not awaiting the call to this method.

Comment: @GauravMantri added the full code

Comment: @GauravMantri Change Main to async and await analyser.GetBlobFileProperties(), also change all async void to async Task.

Comment: @auburg updated with the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is indeed not waiting for the async operation to finish.

Cheap fix would be to simply change the following line of code:

```
analyser.GetBlobFileProperties();
```

to

```
analyser.GetBlobFileProperties().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and you should not get the problem you're getting.

Comment: No problem will remain because of this line `public async void GetBlobFileProperties()` it is not awaitable and should be changed to `async Task`. Also I think that changing Main to `async` and using `await` is more convinient way to solve this problem.

Comment: updated method to: public async Task<bool> GetBlobFileProperties() and used GetAwaiter().GetResult(); works fine thank !  @AlexeyRumyantsev cannot change Main method to async

Comment: @sm101 what version of C# you use? Main method can be made async since 7.1. Or it is some business restriction?